# stackoverflow exception on calling asmx service from scheduletaskagent in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, asmx

I have a wp8 project that references a wp8 class library. The class library has a service reference. I also have a wp8 task agent project that references the class library to update the live tiles. When calling the service methods from the phone project everything works great but when I call a service method from the task agent I start getting a stack overflow exception or out of memory exception.

```
    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
       string userName = GetUserName(); //from isolated storage
       MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient ();
       client.GetDataCompleted += client_GetData;

       client.GetDataAsync(username);
    }
```

The error occurs on GetDataAsync. However when I use the same code in the phone app(not the task agent) everything is working fine.

Has anyone noticed something similar?

Thanks,
Kunal

Comment: You are probably using more memory than you're allowed to - that's a reasonable explanation to why that is happening in the background task and not in your app. However, from the code that you added, it's not really clear why it happens. Look into GetDataAsync method and see if there's anything that could be raising memory usage so much.

Comment: It looks like the error is thrown in system.reflection.ilgenerate. I think this is due to the reference file being too large and to deserialize this its throwing a out of memory. Im using a third party service and they have all their service methods in one file. I'll see if I can remove some references and may be then it will work.

Comment: So I removed the unused references from the auto generated Reference.cs and that reduced it 5x its original. Now the task agent runs fine.